# Convert csv values into table rows using xml. Can anyone please explain how below mentioned queries will work

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, csv

Please Explain this code.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl 
(Name VARCHAR(100),DependsOnCSV VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES
    ('a','b,c'),
    ('b','d'),
    ('c',''),
    ('d',''),
    ('e','g'),
    ('f','b,e,a,g'),
    ('g',''),
    ('h','a')

CREATE FUNCTION Split
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select 
    r.value('.','varchar(5)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
GO

SELECT
  tbl.Name,
  split.val AS [DependsOn-Rows]
FROM tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(tbl.DependsOnCSV,',') split
```

Comment: Do not tag multiple DBMSs. Do you ever write same query for all of those?

Comment: How does your comment giving any solution to my question.@nikhil

Comment: It's not a solution but a suggestion to make people here take your post more seriously. Things like question clarity, proper tags, code formatting etc matter a lot when someone here on SO is reading your post, most of them will not even bother to got through it otherwise. No offence, I wanted you to understand few things as you are new on SO.

Comment: @StutiNautiyal It doesn't; that's why it's been posted as a comment, not as an answer. But it's an excellent comment: what database are you using? There's no point asking a question about SQL Server and tagging it "MySQL", as the people reading the MySQL tag are unlikely to be experts on SQL Server; you're wasting their time and yours.

Comment: Which parts do you already understand?  Which parts are confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my explanation for this script

following creates a sample database table containing an object (name) and its dependends on an other field (DependsOnCSV) seperated by comma

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (Name VARCHAR(100),DependsOnCSV VARCHAR(100))
```

Following code populates above table with sample data. This is a new syntax for many developers. If you are working with a prier version of SQL2012 you might have to convert it into INSERT INTO .. SELECT ... for each row

```
INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES
    ('a','b,c'),
    ('b','d'),
    ('c',''),
    ('d',''),
    ('e','g'),
    ('f','b,e,a,g'),
    ('g',''),
    ('h','a')
```

Below function is used to [split string values in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx). You can find many similar functions. SQL Server 2016 is being shipped with a built-in split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select 
    r.value('.','varchar(5)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
GO
```

This SELECT statements returns objects with each of their dependens by splitting the DependendOnCVS column by "," comma

```
SELECT
  tbl.Name,
  split.val AS [DependsOn-Rows]
FROM tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(tbl.DependsOnCSV,',') split
```

I hope the above code is readable now

Comment: It's worth to mention, that the `Split` function was much better be done as inlineable TVF (without `BEGIN ... END`). Further more the `N` before literal strings should be everywhere. Further more the `<root>`-level can be ommited, the `.nodes('//root/r')` should be `.nodes('/root/r')` or - without the `<root>` just `.nodes('/r')`. Further more the `varchar(5)` is really not adviseable for a "generic" function and last but not least `tbl AS tbl` is at least confusing :)